# How to decribe an action with STRIPS?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

The state space is decribed with 3 boolean variables $p,q$ and $r$ (so we have 8 states total). We have an action, let's say $a$. Action $a$ can be executed when $p=\text{False}$ and $q=\text{True}$ and the result is $p=\text{True}$, $q=\text{False}$ and $r=\text{False}$

How can we describe this action with [STRIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS)? My problem is this: since it isn't allowed on STRIPS to have negative literals, how can I describe it? For example, $\text{precondition}(a) = \{ \neg p,q \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of propositional STRIPS planning is a quadruple $\langle P,O,I,G \rangle$

- $P$ is the set of atomic ground formulas;
- $O$ is the set of *operators* (actions); an operator  $a \in O$ has the form $Pre \Rightarrow Post$, where $Pre$ is a satisfiable conjuction of positive ($a^+$) and negative *preconditions* ($a^-$) of the operator; $Post$ is a satisfiable conjunction of positive ($a_+$) and negative ($a_-$) *postconditions* of the operator ($a_+$ is called the *add list*, $a_-$ is called the *delete list*);
- $I \subseteq P$ is the *initial state*;
- $G = \langle G_+, G_- \rangle$, called the *goals*, is a satisfiable conjunction of positive and negative conjunctions;
- the state $S$ is a subset of $P$.

The result of applying operator (action) $a$ on state $S$ is:

- $(S \cup a_+) \setminus a_-\quad$ if $a^+ \subseteq S$ and $S \cap a^- = \emptyset$
- $S$ otherwise

In your example simply set: 
$$a^+ = \{q\}, \quad a^- = \{p\}$$
$$a_+ = \{p\}, \quad a_- = \{q,r\}$$

For a formal definition and a nice computational complexity characterizations of STRIPS with various constraints on the preconditions/postconditions see:
[The Computational Complexity of Propositional STRIPS Planning (1994), by Tom Bylander](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~ki/teaching/ws0708/aipsem/papers/bylander%3aaij-1994.pdf).

Comment: in Blocks-World Example we describe the preconditions for example as: on(A,B) , on(C,B) .....What I am saying is this maybe in our problem we have something like is_true(p), is_false(q).... Am i right ?

Comment: @AdaselPomik: yes; on(A,B) is an atomic formula ($on(A,B) \in P$), that can be true or false. If A is on B then $on(A,B)$ is in the current state ($on(A,B) \in S$). Your "is_true(p)" in STRIPS is "represented" with $p \in S$, "is_false(p)" is represented with $p \notin S$

Comment: The negative preconditions are $a^-$ (superscript minus), the negative postconditions are $a_-$ (subscript minus). Perhaps the notation is a little bit confusing, but it is the one used by Bylander.

Comment: My problem with your answer is that , because my book ( Russel and Norvig )doesn't say anything about positive and negative preconditions, I can't use them.Book says "only positive literals in states". So if I write , preconditions(a) = q add(a)=p and delete(a)=q,r , is this correct ?

Comment: @AdaselPomik: yes :-) To be pedantic: preconditions(a) = {q}, add(a) = {p), delete(a) = {q,r}

Comment: the reason I asked the question is, because my notation is wrong. A simple example : let's say we have a state space described by $2$ boolean variables. So ALL states are $S=\{TT,TF,FT,FF\}$,and $TF$ means $p=True$ and $q=False$. Now let's say we have action a which can be executed when $p=T$ and the result is $q=T$. With my notation we have  $pre(a)=\{p\}$ (this means that $q=F$(because we don't refer to $q$, so it's $F$)), but the given rule says "executed when $p=T$" and I interpret this as can be executed on states $\{TT,TF\}$. So my notation isn't correct.Am I Right?

Comment: Yes it is not correct and the only way to fix it is: 1) use Bylander notation and use *two* sets of preconditions $pre^+, pre^-$: the positive preconditions and the negative preconditions; or 2) introduce two new positive variables: $notp, notq$ and $notr$, and in this case $pre(a) = \{p, notq\}$, and $add(a) = \{ notp, q, notr \}, del(a) = \{ p, notq, r \}$

Comment: Can I name the states  for example(general example) state $TT$ is $s1$ state $TF$ is $s2$ ..... and then say $pre(a)=\{s1,s2\}$ ...  ????